# Display nodes without 'name' property neo4j browser

Tags: neo4j

I have nodes which don't have the 'name' property, in that case in the browser, it doesn't show a default property to be shown. Most of the nodes look blank, which isn't good for visualization. How to display that better in such cases?

Comment: What is your version of neo4j? You can display object id if your node has no property.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the two images to explain what to do.

Say for whatever reason the user node does not display anything.

[image: A label without a display]

To display something, first click on the top user as shown below.

[image: Enabling display of name property]

Now in the bottom pan you see the properties of the user label. Now click what ever property that you what to be displayed. I want name so I click name below.
[image: Name property clicked]

Answer (score 1):

When you perform a query in the browser, the viz is inside a panel.

In the top bar of this panel, you will see the facet for labels and relationships.

If you click on one of those elements, the bottom bar will change, and will allow you to change the field to display, the color and size.